# Wallet.dat corrupted

Tags: wallet.dat

I ran Bitcoin during 2009 and 2010.

I found an old file I had renamed to xxxx.dat. I recently downloaded the Bitcoin.org wallet and let it run.

I get the "wallet.dat corrupted, salvage failed" message after I put in the file I believe to be my old wallet.dat. I have deleted the installation and restarted my computer. I hope to be able to start over. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what it is you are trying to do? Do you have bitcoins you want to recover?

Comment: I'm trying to see how many bitcoins are in it, and to recover them to cash in.

Comment: I fear all of my bitcoins and altcoins have been stolen by mg

Answer (score 1):

> **I ran the blockchain during 2009 and 2010**

By "ran the blockchain" I guess you mean you ran Bitcoin-core wallet software sometimes known as Bitcoin-qt.

> **I downloaded the Bitcoin.org wallet**

Bitcoin.org lists many wallets, I guess you mean Bitcoin-core wallet.

> **I found an old file I had renamed to xxxx.dat.**

There are many different data formats and software applications that use ".dat" as a filename extension. So your xxxx.dat might not be a wallet.

> **Any suggestions?**

Check the format of your xxxx.dat file. See if it matches the expected format.

There are tools that *might* assist with this - such as [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet).

Otherwise maybe you have to download an ancient version of Bitcoin-core

Comment: It is from 2011. I thought it was a wallet from bitcoin core I purchased in 2011 to 2012.

Comment: Down load an ancient? I thought it would handle any bitcoin core wallet. Back then it was the only wallet. I've forgotten who or where I purchased them.

Comment: Bitcoin wallets are free, you would not have needed to purchase a wallet in 2011 or 2012.